# Incorrect reading order

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I am evaluating some code that was sent to me, and I don't follow why it is happening.

**[edit]:** The code is generated by Lectora, an e-learning software, so nothing was done by hand. The ugly inline code cannot by shoved in a stylesheet.

**[Edit 2]** The *buttonxxx* is some feature it looks like in lectora to allow you to make invisable hotspots, sort of like an image map. I don't have the software, and the person making it isn't too tech savvy.

HTML

```
<p  style="margin-left:0px;text-indent:0px;line-height:1.160;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;text-align:left;" >
<a href="##Action 7515"  ><span class="text3708Font1"  >Table of 
Contents</span ></a ><a href="##Action 7515"  ><span class="text3708Font2" style="background-color:transparent" >
</span ></a ></p >
<p  style="margin-left:0px;text-indent:0px;line-height:1.160;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;text-align:left;" >
<span class="text3708Font3" style="background-color:transparent" >
&nbsp;</span ></p >
<p  style="margin-left:0px;text-indent:0px;line-height:1.160;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;text-align:left;" >
<a href="##Action 3710"  ><span class="text3708Font4"  >Edgar's 
Dilemma</span></a ><span class="text3708Font5" style="background-color:transparent" >
</span ></p >
```

---

The JavaScript that I think is applicable. There is about 530 lines of JS in the page.

```
button6458 = new ObjButton('button6458','table of contents',1,69,70,37,1,8,'div')
button6458.setImages('transbtn.gif',null,null,'images/')
button6458.onUp = button6458onUp
button6458.hasOnUp = true
button6458.capture=4
button6458.build()

button6459 = new ObjButton('button6459','course beginning story',2,112,67,36,1,9,'div')
button6459.setImages('transbtn.gif',null,null,'images/')
button6459.onUp = button6459onUp
button6459.hasOnUp = true
button6459.capture=4
button6459.build()
```

But if I navigate this using a screen reader, it is announced as:

> Table of Contents [link], [link] (a space after the s in contents), Edgar’s Dilemma [link], [link] (a space character in the space between edgar & what is 508), Table of Contents (now announced as “go to table of contents [link]”), Edgar’s Dilemma (now announced as “Go to course beginning story [link]”)

Any ideas as to why the anchors are read, then the javascript would be great.

---

### **Solution:**

About halfway into the source code, some JS was wrote. This makes the second set of links via the JS code block above. If we strip the junk out, the source code essentially becomes:

```
<a href="#">Table of contents</a>
<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
<a href="#">Edgar's Delimma</a>
<a href="#">go to Table of contents</a>
<a href="#">go toEdgar's Delimma</a>
```

I haven't figured out how the `&nbsp;` is being created.

Comment: Have you validated your HTML markup to ensure that it is valid? (Given the presence of inline styles and random spaces it looks like it was developed by someone not well-versed in HTML development, hand-code, and with a great probability of being invalid.)

Comment: Further, you need to pare this down to the relevant HTML. Do your own work, deleting irrelevant content and markup (such as the inline styles) until you cannot delete anything further without 'fixing' the problem.

Comment: @Phrogz I'd say the code is generated by a rich-text editor instead. Seeing the class names et al...

Comment: @Florian You are likely correct.

Comment: @Phrogz  I did not develop this code, nor the page. It was spit out by lectora. I will update above

Comment: and why can't the ugly inline styles be shoved into a stylesheet exactly?  all CSS belongs in a style sheet.. all JS belongs in JS..   oh and FYI, there is actually missing code here...  such as the ObjButton -- and without that no one can help...  also e-learning is crap -- buy a book...

Comment: @Ryan No offense intended; I did not imagine you wrote this. However, the question stands: "Have you validated your HTML?" And then: have you inspected the DOM after the JavaScript has run in a browser like Chrome, to see how the structure may have shifted?

Comment: @Justin I cannot dictate how my company chooses to do things. I know the code is junk. I just want to know why it goes html anchors then JS vs anchor, js, anchor, js.

Comment: @Phrogz,I didn't validate, nor inspected Dom. I updated it to my real question

Answer (score 0):

Your source code in the first block can be simplified to

```
<p><a href="##Action 7515">Table of Contents</a><a href="##Action 7515"></a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="##Action 3710">Edgar's Dilemma</a></p >
```

and it appears that your output is stripping the `<p>&nbsp;</p>` element because there is no content there to be read, but it's assuming that the link after the "Table of Contents" link is significant and retaining that. Because there is no text to form the link, it's doing its best.

I suspect that the link which is being announced after "Edgar's Dilemma" is similarly coded.

Quite *why* there should be an empty link in the code may be down to Lectora or the person who put the e-learning package together. Given the change of text style in the source code, it could be because of a font change at the end of the "Table of Contents" link — Microsoft Word can do this, when a paragraph mark retains a font setting which has been overridden for the text itself.

Comment: The javascript is using the id in the span to create a link, so it becomes <a href="">&nbsp;</a> somehow.

Comment: @RyanB: I don't understand. There's isn't an `id` in the `span`. There's an extra, empty `<a href=...>` element which is being read out (see my simplification of your source).

Comment: Sorry I meant class. Their are like 20 text3708font _x_ classes.